# What does 'to' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Two people are arguing about the superiority of their dog. The argument goes as following:

```
NATALYA STEPANOVNA: Why talk rot? It's awful! It's time your Guess was shot, and you compare him with Squeezer!
```

LOMOV: Excuse me; I cannot continue this discussion: my heart is palpitating.

NATALYA STEPANOVNA: I've noticed that those hunters argue most who know least.

LOMOV: Madam, please be silent. ... My heart is going to pieces. ... [Shouts] Shut up!

NATALYA STEPANOVNA: I shan't shut up until you acknowledge that Squeezer is a hundred times better than your Guess!

LOMOV: A hundred times worse! **Be hanged to your Squeezer!** His head ... eyes ... shoulder ...

NATALYA STEPANOVNA: There's no need to hang your silly Guess; he's half-dead already!

LOMOV: [Weeps] Shut up! My heart's bursting!

NATALYA STEPANOVNA: I shan't shut up.

(Guess and Squeezer are the dogs' names.)

Comment: This is a weird looking and sounding sentence. Can you give some more context, or, more importantly, source? I've never seen the past form of Hang written as "hanged".

Comment: If I recall correctly, *hanged* refers to hanging someone (something?) to death, and it's been mentioned on ELL somewhere. The problem is, I can't remember where!

Comment: That is true that *hanged* can mean to hang something to death, but that doesn't sound like what it's talking about here, though I'm not quite sure what it *is* talking about.

Comment: "Be hanged *to*" is not idiomatic English.  Idiomatic, if archaic, would be "Your Squeezer be hanged!"  *To hang s.o.* is to execute a person by attaching a rope to their neck and then hoisting them up or dropping them from a platform.  The past tense is "hanged", although many native speakers say "hung":  *They hung [sic] him from a tree*. (nonstandard)

Comment: @zerohedge It is from The Proposal by Anton Chekhov.

Comment: @Kaptan Singh: It is from a *translation* of a Chekhov play.

Comment: A person gets hanged. A photograph or painting gets hung on the wall.

Answer (score 1):

I think the definition #3, b from [American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hang) applies to your context:

> Used to express exasperation or disgust: I'll be hanged! Hang it all!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express that A and B are physically connected, such that moving A also moves B, *to* is the preposition to use (i.e. *connected to*, *tied to*, *leashed to*, etc.)

While it's unusual to see *hanged* being used in this manner, that's how I would interpret it.  I believe the implication is that the subject of this sentence is so attached physically (by a leash, etc.) to his dog that his dog can figuratively drag him around, even at the detriment of the subject.